# Hibernate Envers Criteria API adds 'order by' clause automatically

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Hibernate **Envers** (Criteria API) automatically adds a clause **'`order by`'** by ID Revision when not is added projection and not is added order. This procedure burdening the query  performance and show warning that the **I/O limit was exceeded**.

```
AuditQuery query = getAuditReader().createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(MyEntity.class, false, true);
```

With '`order by`' the query uses **300,000** and without 'order by' **30,000 bytes**.
It is an audit table with more than 5 million lines.

I seek between 30 or 100 results:

```
query.setFirstResult (1);
query.setMaxResults (30);
```

Even without adding a clause 'order by' (`query.addOrder (...);`), envers does. The generated query looks like this, for example:

```
select *
  from (select e.*
          from MY_ENTITY e,
               MY_REVISION_ENTITY re
         where e.ID_REVISAO = re.ID_REVISAO
           and re.ID_COL_EXTRA = 1234
        order by e.ID_REVISAO desc -- PROBLEM!!!
) Where rownum <= 30;
```

I noticed that the `org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery` class has the following code block in the `list()` method:

```
 if (!hasProjection && !hasOrder) {
   String revisionPropertyPath = verEntCfg.getRevisionNumberPath();
   qb.addOrder(revisionPropertyPath, true);
 }
```

This is a bug?

I understand the importance of ordering for not to take random records, but this should be a free choice.

*I use 4.1.3.Final version of envers.*

Comment: The query cost without `order by` is **19** and **137** with the clause.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that the alternative to improve query performance should be: ***Table Partitioning***. Using the audit strategy: `ValidityAuditStrategy` according to the development guide Hibernate Envers (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-partitioning).

Additionally, customize the Envers for not add default '`order by`'.